# range-v3: What is the idiomatic way to store a range into an existing container?

Tags: c++, range-v3

I have a range based on a forward iterator, so the size isn't known before encountering the end iterator. This iterator is used for a transformation with range-v3:

```
auto src = GetForwardIteratorRange();
auto dest = src | rv::transform([](auto item) { ... }) | r::to<vector>;
```

If I want to do `dest.reserve(100'000)` first, is there a way I can fill this vector later idiomatically with range-v3? Like doing `r::to(dest)` (which doesn't work)?

**Edit:**
I'm not even sure

```
auto src = GetForwardIteratorRange();
auto transform = src | rv::transform([](auto item) { ... });
vector dest;
dest.reserve(100'000);
dest.assign(transform.begin(), transform.end());
```

would work. The [cppreference page on vector::assign](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/assign) sounds as if the implementation can just throw any allocated space away ("The past-the-end iterator is also invalidated.")

I could probably use

```
boost::ranges::copy(transform, back_inserter(dest));
```

or

```
boost::ranges::transform(src, back_inserter(dest), [](auto item) {...});
```

but I'm wondering if I'm overlooking some range-v3 feature here.

Comment: Is 100'000 the exact number of elements for GetForwardIteratorRange? Or is it just a rough estimate?

Comment: A rough estimate.

Comment: I guess you've got a typo. It should've been `r::to<vector>()`; at least that's how its done in std `<ranges>`. But you've missed the braces `()`.

Comment: If the destination is a `std::array` or a `std::span`, I would `zip` the source and destination and write pythonic `for` to avoid manual size management: `for(auto&& [to, from]: rv::zip(spn, src | rv::transform (fun))) to = from;`

Comment: @Red.Wave actually it works without the parentheses: https://godbolt.org/z/qM4jP8Ghr

Comment: So, remember to add the braces when you switch to std. Or create a wrapper with conditional compilation, to avoid confusion on cryptic diagnostics.

Answer (score 0):

Your `reserve` + `assign` code is fine.

The reason that it says all iterators are invalidated is because it destroys all the exisiting elements, then fills the empty space with the new elements, which in general might mean an allocation, but in your case won't, if your estimate is good.

`ranges::to` accepts a pack of arguments to pass to the constructor besides the iterators, so you could write a wrapper type that reserved space in a vector, then assigned into it.

```
template <typename T, typename A = std::allocator<T>>
class reserving_vector {
    std::vector<T, A> vector;
public:
    template <std::ranges::input_range R>
    reserving_vector(std::ranges::from_range_t, R range, size_t reservation) {
        vector.reserve(reservation);
        vector.assign(begin(range), end(range));
    }
    operator std::vector<T, A>() && { return std::move(vector); }
};

template <std::ranges::input_range R, typename A = std::allocator<std::ranges::range_value_t<R>>>
reserving_vector(std::ranges::from_range_t, R, size_t) -> reserving_vector<std::ranges::range_value_t<R>, A>;

auto src = GetForwardIteratorRange();
vector dest = src | rv::transform([](auto item) { ... }) | r::to<reserving_vector>(100'000);
```

Comment: No idea why someone downvoted this without a comment, I didn't know about this parameter pack argument!

Comment: I'm not so sure about your `assign` statement though. For `string::assign`, the standard explicitly mentions that `this.swap(string(begin, end))` is a valid implementation. I do not find such a statement for `vector`, but I suspect it may actually be a valid implementation.